# @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment and browser fetch

Tags: typescript, eslint, fetch-api, typescript-eslint

I have the following function, which works like a charm :

```js
type BuildInfo = {
  git: {
    branch: string
    commitId: string
    shortCommitId: string
    commitTime: string | number
  }
  build: {
    name: string
    version: string
    time: string | number
  }
}

const getRemoteRevision = async () => {
  try {
    const response = await fetch('/meta.json')
    const version: BuildInfo = await response.json()

    return version?.git.commitId
  } catch {}
}
```

I’m using [xojs](https://github.com/xojs/xo) which defines the [`@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment`](https://typescript-eslint.io/rules/no-unsafe-assignment/) eslint rule to the *error* level.

On this particular piece of code, `tsc` is fine and won’t complain about anything being wrong… IDE introspection reveals the following types :

- `getRemoteRevision`: `() => Promise<string | undefined>`
- `response`: `Response`
- `version`: `BuildInfo`
- `Body.json()`: `Promise<any>`

So, as you could guess by the code, the eslint rule and the types… ESLint is not happy and fails with the `@typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment` error on the line that defines the `version` variable.

I can’t find any way to make the error go away ! I tried several things, which all failed :

```js
const response: Response & { json: () => Promise<BuildInfo> } = await fetch('/meta.json')
const version: BuildInfo = await response.json()

// ---

const version: BuildInfo = await response.json<Promise<BuildInfo>>()

// ---

const version = (await response.json()) as unknown as BuildInfo
```

I’m pretty new to TypeScript and I really don’t understand in what way is this code wrong ? Or maybe is it the ESLint rule which is broken ? Or too restrictive ?

Also the weird thing is that `tsc` is ok with this code (while running in **strict mode**) and somehow ESLint isn’t ?

Answer (score 0):

The rule reports here because you're assigning `any` to a variable typed as something that's not `any`. The explicit annotation doesn't change the fact that there is an inherently unsafe assignment occurring here!

Your code is working on the assumption that your endpoint will always match the shape of `BuildInfo` - but given it's an external API call there are a lot of ways where this might fail and return an object that doesn't match the shape.

If you're okay with this unsafety in your codebase then you can use one of the following solutions::

```
// 1) Use a disable comment to suppress the error:

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-unsafe-assignment -- we're assuming the backend returns the correct shape
const version: BuildInfo = await response.json();
```

```
// 2) Use an assertion to change from `any` to the desired type:

const version = (await response.json()) as BuildInfo;
```

As for what you can do if you want to instead be safe - in a nutshell you would want to validate that the result is an object that matches the expected type. There are libraries like [zod](https://www.npmjs.com/package/zod) which allow you to pretty easily perform such validations, or you could hand-craft your own.

Comment: Thx for answering, but sadly your solution doesn’t work… The issue seems to be related to my TS config… I opened an issue in the xo repository (https://github.com/xojs/xo/issues/719) for that matter. The BuildInfo type is declared in a custom Vite plugin located at the project root (my-plugin.ts) and I’m importing it in the code of a custom React hook used by my app (src/hooks/my-hook.ts). TS is ok with this, but not ESLint. In the end, I created a .d.ts file under the src dir to declare the type and then used it in my app code as-is. The Vite plugin is then importing it without any issue.

Comment: based on the repo you linked in the issue - i believe your problem would be that the tsconfig used by the lint run does not include the imported file (eg the tsconfig includes `./src/**/*.ts`, but the imported file is `./vite-plugin.ts`). The lint run cannot and does not expand the program to include new files - hence TS resolves the import to `any`, causing your issue.

Comment: That’s what I suspected… But the tsconfig  `references` tsconfig.node, which includes `*.ts`, so I would expect the linter to follow this reference. Therefore, is it a linter issue ? A config issue ? And is my « fix » okay (in the end, it works) ?

Comment: The linter does not support project references - https://typescript-eslint.io/linting/troubleshooting#are-typescript-project-references-supported

Comment: Oh, right. Read the linked issue, if I understood correctly that means I would have to set the `parserOptions.project` option of typescript-eslint to resolve my problem, right ?
If this is the case, well I’m in no luck as xo doesn’t allow to set anything else than a string for the `parserOptions.project` option (its value is used to perform a `path.resolve`…).

Comment: I would advise agains using type casting unless you are absolutely certain of the response. In this case I would use:

`const version: unknown = await response.json();`